# How I can make my variable read in other way than make it global

Tags: android-studio

why the sum variable can't read in if statement, I thought is working. 
My question how I can make it readable inside of if statement.

```
private int r1, r2, num1, num2, num3, sum; /*I set it global but it cant
private int count = 0;                       /*read inside of onClickButton

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    giveNewRandom();

}
private void giveNewRandom() {
    Random rand = new Random();
    r1 = rand.nextInt(100);
    r2 = rand.nextInt(100);

    TextView e1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView5);
    e1.setText(Integer.toString(r1));
    TextView e2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView6);
    e2.setText(Integer.toString(r2));
    num1 = Integer.parseInt(e1.getText().toString());
    num2 = Integer.parseInt(e2.getText().toString());
    sum = num1 + num2;
    EditText e3 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText5);
    num3 = Integer.parseInt(e3.getText().toString());
}

public void onButtonClick(View v) {
    if (num3 == sum){                /*sum become red when I set it local
        count ++;}
     else{
        count --;}
        TextView t1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView4);
        t1.setText(""+ count);
        giveNewRandom();
}
```

help me guys. Thank you in advance ^_^

Comment: If possible, please try to post only the relevant code; for example, you do not need most of the code in `giveNewRandom`.

Comment: Thank you for your concern, but I need to do that since I'm not good in explaining and I'm first timer here. thank you for your help I really appreciate it ^_^